# cloudformation lifecycle events cannot publish to sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a lifecycle event for an autoscaling group in AWS Amazon cloudformation, however I keep getting a really ambiguous error back when deploying my stack:

`Unable to publish test message to notification target 
arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:example-topic using IAM role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/SNSExample. Please check your target and role configuration and try to put lifecycle hook again.`

I have tested the SNS topic and it can send emails fine and my code appears to be in line with what Amazon suggest:

```
"ASGLifecycleEvent": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook",
  "Properties": {
    "AutoScalingGroupName": "ASG-179ZOVNY8SEFT",
    "LifecycleTransition": "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING",
    "NotificationTargetARN": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:example-topic",
    "RoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/SNSExample"
  },
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
      "id": "83129091-8efc-477d-86ef-9a08de4d6fac"
    }
  }
}
```

And I have granted full access to everything in that IAM role, however I still get this error message. Does anyone have any other ideas what could really be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your `SNSExample` role needs to delegate permissions from the **AutoScalingNotificationAccessRole** managed policy to the `autoscaling.amazonaws.com` service via an associated Trust Policy (the [`AssumeRolePolicyDocument`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-assumerolepolicydocument) Property in the CloudFormation Resource):

```
  SNSExample:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [autoscaling.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AutoScalingNotificationAccessRole
```

(You can also delegate access to `sns:Publish` action instead of using the managed policy, but I recommend the managed policy because it will stay up to date if additional permissions are required for this service in the future.)

See the [Receive Notification Using Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html#sns-notifications) part of the Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks section of the Auto Scaling User Guide for more information.